# How do I pass parameters to Google Apps Script and why am I receiving an error?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am attempting to run the sample script included in the `Scripts` connected app. The code is as follows:

```
function listFilesInFolder(id) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var file;
  var name;

  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    Logger.log(name);
  }
};
```

I have two questions about this:

1. Why am I receiving an error stating: `Access denied: DriveApp. (line 10, file "Code")`?
2. How do I pass in parameters for `id` when trying to run the script?

Also, an authorization window popped up to request access to drive by the script, which I allowed.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time and don't cross-posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can call this function from another one, or you can define 'id' inside of it. Example:

```
function testFilesInFolder() {
  listFilesInFolder('folderIdHere');
}
```

or can define 'id' inside there:

```
function listFilesInFolder(id) {

  id = 'folderIdHere'

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(id);
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var file;
  var name;

  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    Logger.log(name);
  }
};
```